# While loop doesn't stop looping

Tags: python-3.x

I'm pretty new to python. I wrote this to emulate rolling dice;

```
dsides = int(input("how many sides do your dice have?"))
print("Your dice has " + str(dsides) +" sides")

dint = int(input("How many dice do you want to roll?"))
print("You are rolling " + str(dint) + " dice")

import random
y=0

while( y < dint ):
    out = random.randint(1, int(dsides))
    print(str(out))
    y+1
```

the problem is the while loop doesn't stop looping on integer 'dint' quantity....

Comment: That's because you didn't re assigned the `y` after increasing. change it to `y=y+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line should read

```
y=y+1
```

Now it is not doing anything to y.

(A general tip for debugging: If your loop does not terminate, print out the loop value to see what is happening to it)

Comment: We have all been there once ;-) - please mark the answer as accepted (which will also give you some so-points)

Comment: The problem debugging for me is that I can only do it via code. I'm coding at college and due to admin rights etc I can only use online consoles which never seem to include debugs.... So I knew the loop was stuck in a loop because it wasn't returning anything.

Comment: what about adding print(y) ?

Comment: Well I'm attempting to have it print a separate variable so that the output looks like this; 
    Rolls: 3 - 2 - 5 -3

but I'm not to sure how to do that, don't know how to turn 'dint' into a numbered array, for instance if 'dint' = 4 I want an array 'arrrolls' = [1, 2 , 3, 4]

Comment: Of cource, when you've found and corrected the bug, you remove the debugging output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put y+=1 or y=y+1 at the end of the while.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this y+1 you have to do this y = y+1